# Flutter: AssetsAudioPlayer stopping other music

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-audioplayers

I have a quiz app. When the user answers correctly, the correct sound is heard for 2 seconds, and when the user answers incorrectly, the wrong sound is heard for 2 seconds. I use AssetsAudioPlayer for this. The problem is this: While AssetsAudioPlayer is playing, the music and video the user is listening to stops. I don't want it to stop. What can I do?

```
final assetsAudioPlayer = AssetsAudioPlayer();                 
assetsAudioPlayer.open(Audio("sounds/correct.mp3"),);
```